# How to show a map of the User's Location in the User's profile with Address Field and Geofield

Tags: google-maps, entities, location

So, the location + Gmap module showed a map of the User's address in the user's profile once it was geocoded. Is there an equivalent widget that will show a map of the user's address in the profile itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use module [getlocations](http://drupal.org/project/getlocations).  It also supports paths like "/getlocations/user/xxx" and "/getlocations/users" for location-enabled users